# Registering for UIAutomation structure change events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am working on an application that is monitoring a given application for automation events. Currently, I am working specifically with structure change events on a WPF application that I developed.

```
public void MonitorStructureChangedEvents(AutomationElement element)
{
    Automation.AddStructureChangedEventHandler(element, TreeScope.Subtree, OnStructureChanged);
}
```

where in this case, `element` is the root `AutomationElement` of the Application (its main window). The WPF application in question is just a `Window` with a grid view and various controls (text boxes, checkboxes, buttons, etc). It is a test app I have developed specifically for testing UIAutomation events.

I am using a Unit Test project to test these events, and I am launching the application in the `ClassInitialize` decorated method. I do not register for `StructureChanged` events until the application is launched and I have located it via WMI in my `TestMethod`. The application is spawned as a new process.

However, upon registering for structure changed events, I receive structure changed events for all the elements in the main window of my application, even though the WPF application is effectively idling. I have buttons in the main window that add and remove controls to test `StructureChanged` events, and it does work, however I am unsure why when I initially register, all of the elements fire a structure changed event.

Edit: After further testing, I notice that these events are fired as soon as I either click on the application window, or hover over a button. It then fires a structure changed event for every element in the app one time. After it is done, it no longer fires a structure changed event if I hover over a button, or click on the application (even after clicking on another application or the desktop)

Edit2: After further testing, I believe I figured out the cause of the issue, but no solution yet. When I try to `TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(rootApplicationElement)` I receive a null. It appears that the `AutomationElement` that I am acquiring has no children cached. Once I add the `StructureChanged` event handler on the element, the `TreeWalker` method works, and I get a valid element. It seems when I activate the window after this, that's when it realizes that it now has all these new child elements. Is there a way to cache all the descendants of the `rootApplicationElement` so that before I add the event handler, I can walk the entire subtree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following method

```
CacheRequest request = new CacheRequest();
request.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Descendants;
using (request.Activate())
{
    rootApplicationElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children,
           new PropertyCondition(AutomationElementIdentifiers.ProcessIdProperty, ApplicationInstance.ProcessId))[0];
}
```

I do not advise that people acquire a root element in this fashion, since if an application has more than one window you will get more than one result, but this was tailored to a specific testing need.